# Django-ckeditor 404 errors

Tags: javascript, python, django, ckeditor

I'm receiving several 404-errors when using django-ckeditor.

[This is what my static folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlQ9a.png)

The first is on the `ckeditor.js` file, which is located at `static/boot/ckeditor/ckeditor` and the error I receive is as follows: `"GET /static/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1657`

Following, I receive a few errors on other documents that are actually in the folders where I get an error:

```
"GET .../AGAPE/static/boot/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js?t=JB9C HTTP/1.1" 404 2494

"GET .../AGAPE/static/boot/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=JB9C HTTP/1.1" 404 2548

"GET .../AGAPE/static/boot/ckeditor/ckeditor/lang/nl.js?t=JB9C HTTP/1.1" 404 2497
```

For the last three, I imagine that the error is caused by the characters that are added at the end of the file name, e.g. `?t=JB9C`, but I don't get why these characters are added.

Additionally, my `settings.py` file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/boot/')
STATIC_FILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'boot'),]

MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
MEDIA_URL="/media/"

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(STATIC_ROOT), 'ckeditor/ckeditor/')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDIT_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
   'default': {
        'toolbar':[ ['CodeSnippet', ], ],
        'height': 400,
        'width': 900,
        'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser',
        'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet',
   },
}
```

And the relevant `models.py` file (in the relevant app):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The `admin.py` file (in the relevant app):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post 

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'status','created_on')
    list_filter = ("status",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    class Media:
        js = ('ckeditor.js',)
        # do not write '/static/ckeditor.js' as Django automatically looks 
        # in the static folder

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

The `urls.py` file (global):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from AGAPE import views
from articles import views
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('i8n/', include('django_translation_flags.urls')),
    url(r'^home', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^overagape', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='overagape.html'),name='over_agape'),
    url(r'^QUIZ/', include('QUIZ.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
    url(r'^aspecteen', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='aspecteen.html'), name='aspecteen'),
    url(r'^aspecttwee', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='aspecttwee.html'), name='aspecttwee'),
    url(r'^aspectdrie',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='aspectdrie.html'),name='aspectdrie'),
    url(r'^aspectvier',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='aspectvier.html'),name='aspectvier'),
    url(r'^aspectvijf',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='aspectvijf.html'),name='aspectvijf'),
    url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include ('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem was about the script I call ckeditor in the template.

Before it was like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static ' ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static ' ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
```

and the space between apostrophe symbol and ckeditor path caused django to call it as;

```
"GET /static/%20ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1706    
"GET /static/%20ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1718
```

problem has gone after deleting the space. Could be helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

add the following script at the end

```html
  <script>               
      CKEDITOR.replace( '.ckeditor');
   </script>
```